# Grab two values in loop, check box and variable. Only grabbing checkbox? php w screenshot

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

i make a sql query  asking for data(its a text question), i output the (question) with a checkbox to the left of it and an input field underneath it to give point worth to it(like a teacher making an exam) . All in a loop w arrays. It outputs the correctly checked questions but **only will assign point values to first three questions if there checked**. so if i check q1 q2 and q4 it will output q1 q2 q4 and q1 points q2points. Thats my problem, I only want to be able to select three total questions and assign those questions their points.

php in the html

```
$sql = " SELECT Question  FROM examQuestions";
$result = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxvar[]" value="'.$row["Question"].'">'.$row["Question"].'<input placeholder="10" class="form-control" type="number" name="points[]">'."<br />";
    }
}
```

im trying to output the data using this:

```
$checkboxvar = $_POST['checkboxvar'];
$examName = $_POST['examName'];
$questionWorth = $_POST['points'];

$i=1;
$total = 0;

while ($i < 4) {
    $x = $i - 1;

    echo $checkboxvar[$x];
    echo $questionWorth[$x]."<br />";
    $total = $total + $questionWorth[$x];
    $i = $i +1;
}

echo $total;
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Isn't because you limit to four elements with your **while**: `while($i <4){}`? Try changing `while($i < 4)`with `while($i < count($checkboxvar))`.

Comment: it needs to be 4 to grab 3 checkbox values. that will make it loop as man checked boxes...

Comment: So maybe your problem is beacause when you submit the form, the only checkboxes that are sent are those selected while you will send all the available points, therefore, if you choose c1, c2 and c4 (where **c** stands for checkbox) and then print using your iterator, you will actually print c1, c2, c4 but, p1, p2, p3.

Comment: i see, is there any way to link the  checkbox# nd points #?

Comment: In your checkbox input element you could use a number as **value** which corresponds to your question number. Then, in your php code you could do something like: `$questionWorth[$checkboxvar[$x]]` to get the right points for the specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I told you in the comments try modifying your code like this:

```
$sql = " SELECT Question  FROM examQuestions";
$result = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
$i = 0;

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxvar[]" value="'.$i++.'-'.$row["Question"].'">'.$row["Question"].'<input placeholder="10" class="form-control" type="number" name="points[]">'."<br />";
    }
}
```

And then, to have the right points for the correspondig question something like this:

```
$checkboxvar = $_POST['checkboxvar'];
$examName = $_POST['examName'];
$questionWorth = $_POST['points'];

$i = 0;
$total = 0;

while ($i < 3) {
    $question = explode("-", $checkboxvar[$i]);
    echo $question[1];
    echo $questionWorth[$question[0]]."<br />";
    $total += $questionWorth[$question[0]];
    $i++;
}

echo $total;
```

This should do the work.

Comment: thank you kind sirr, instead of out putting questions it is outputing the index array i.  But the points are right! so were getting somewhere

Comment: @DinoBicBoi I have updated the code so that you can now have the **index** and **question title** separated by the "-" char. You can then use the php `explode()` function to separate the **index** and the **question title** in the second part.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your implied question correctly, you will need some client side (javascript) code that keeps track of the number of checked checkboxes. As soon as one checks three boxes all remaining ones and corresponding text boxes are disabled.

for naive vanilla js solution your php could look like this:

```
$index = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<label><input class='questions' type='checkbox' name='question_{$index}' value='{$row["Question"]}' on_change='limit_to_three(this);'>{$row["Question"]}<label><br>";
    echo "<input class='scores' name='score_{$index}'><br>";
    $index++;
}
```

For modern browsers you would need the following in your javascript :

```
var selected_count = 0;
function limit_to_three(selected_checkbox) {
    if (selected_checkbox.checked) {
        selected_count++;
    } else {
        selected_count--;
    }

    var limit_reached = (selected_count == 3);
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('questions');
    var scores = document.getElementsByClassName('scores');
    for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (!checkboxes[i].checked) {
             checkboxes[i].disabled = scores[i].disabled = limit_reached;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, upon submit, you can assume that only checked question checkboxes will be submitted, so your php code could be like this:

```
$total = 0;
$length = strlen('questions_');
foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
    if (substr($name, 0, $length) == 'questions_') {
        $index = substr($name, $length - strlen($name));
        echo $_POST[$name];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $_POST["scores_{$index}"];
        $total += $_POST["scores_{$index}"];            
    }
}
```

As i said, this is a naive implementation, that sends question texts back and forth. If i were you i would add ID column to your questions table and use it instead of dynamically generated indexes

Then your html could be generated like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<label><input class='questions' type='checkbox' name='question_{$index}' value='{$row["ID"]}' on_change='limit_to_three(this);'>{$row["Question"]}<label><br>";
    echo "<input class='scores' name='score_{$row["ID"]}'><br>";
     }
```

and your receiving php could be like this:

```
$checked = explode(',', $_POST['questions']);
for ($checked as $id) {
    $total += $_POST["scores_{$id}"];
}
```

Also you could retrieve the checked questions by

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE ID IN ({$_POST['questions']})";
```

Comment: You cant control the number of selected checkboxes in php. You need to use javascript in combination with php. php for server side logic and javascript for client side logic.

Comment: i control the number of checked boxes fine in php. its the points array i need help with.